# What is the result of distanceBetween result unites

Tags: android, wgs84

I'm using the function in Android Location class: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double, double, double, double, float[])](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D%29)

To get the distance between two geographical points, but I don't know how the result in results[0] unit, is it in meters, miles or what?

> Distance and bearing are defined using the WGS84 ellipsoid.

But I don't know what "WGS84 ellipsoid" means and how to convert that to meters or miles!

Comment: [Here is the WGS 84 Wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the link that you provided

> Computes the approximate distance in meters between two locations

and

> The computed distance is stored in results[0]